# Batch convert WAV files in directory to MOV using ffmpeg

Tags: loops, batch-file, audio, ffmpeg

I'm new to ffmpeg, and trying to figure out a way to add a still `jpg` to any `wav/mp3/ogg` file found in a directory.

I was hoping to have the cmd pop up asking which directory, say `C:\root\` then the batch would loop through each subdirectory in the inputted directory adding a still image `C:\image.jpg` and saving it as a `mov`

Now I know that sounds fairly intense, but here are a couple I found so far:

```
for %%a in ("*.*") do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 20 -c:a libvo_aacenc -b:a 128k "newfiles\%%~na.mp4"
```

and

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image.jpg -i audio.wav -c:v libx264 -tune stillimage -c:a aac -strict experimental -b:a 192k -pix_fmt yuv420p -shortest out.mov
```

So I was thinking is it possible to loop through a directory, adding a single image to the length of the audio, and output it as a mov?

Comment: Take look here : http://superuser.com/questions/1041816/combine-1-image-1-audio-file-to-make-1-video-using-ffmpeg